# Required tag not working in HTML form

Tags: html, required

What I want to achieve:

1. HTML form to order items.
2. QTY field to only appear when the respective item is selected.
3. Make it required.

What problems I'm facing:

1. I was trying out the required tag for the **NAME**, however when I submit my form without filling up the name, the form allows me to submit and does not prompt me to fill up the name field.
2. Have not come up with the code for "**What I want to achieve: 2**"

```html
<form>
  NAME
  <input type="text" name="NAME" id="NAME" required/> <br />
  <br>
  EMAIL
  <input type="email" name="EMAIL" id="EMAIL"> <br />
  <br>
  DEPARTMENT
  <select name="DEPARTMENT" id="DEPARTMENT">
    <option>HR</option>
    <option>DMS</option>
    <option>RIM</option>
  </select><br />
  <br>
  PURPOSE
  <select name="PURPOSE" id="PURPOSE">
    <option>NEW KIT</option>
    <option>EXCHANGE KIT</option>
  </select><br/>
  <br>
  SHIRT 1 
  <select name="SHIRT1" id="SHIRT1">
    <option></option>
    <option>XS</option>
    <option>S</option>
    <option>M</option>
    <option>L</option>
    <option>XL</option>
    <option>2XL</option>
    <option>3XL</option>
    <option>4XL</option>
    <option>5XL</option>
    <option>6XL</option>
    <option>7XL</option>
  </select><br />
  <br>
  QTY
  <SELECT name="QTY1" id="QTY1">
    <option></option>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
  </SELECT> <br />
  <br>
  PANT 1
  <select name="PANT1" id="PANT1">
    <option></option>
    <option>24</option>
    <option>25</option>
    <option>26</option>
    <option>27</option>
    <option>28</option>
    <option>29</option>
    <option>30</option>
    <option>31</option>
    <option>32</option>
    <option>33</option>
    <option>34</option>
    <option>35</option>
    <option>36</option>
    <option>37</option>
    <option>38</option>
    <option>39</option>
    <option>40</option>
    <option>41</option>
    <option>42</option>
    <option>43</option>
    <option>44</option>
    <option>45</option>
    <option>46</option>
    <option>47</option>
    <option>48</option>
  </select><br />
  <br>
  QTY
  <select name="QTY2" id="QTY2">
    <option></option>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
  </select>
  <br />
  <br>
  SHIRT 2
  <select name="SHIRT2" id="SHIRT2">
    <option></option>
    <option>XS</option>
    <option>S</option>
    <option>M</option>
    <option>L</option>
    <option>XL</option>
    <option>2XL</option>
    <option>3XL</option>
    <option>4XL</option>
    <option>5XL</option>
  </select>
  <br />
  <br>
  QTY
  <SELECT name="QTY3" id="QTY3">
    <option></option>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
  </SELECT>
  <br />
  <br>
  PANT 2
  <select name="PANT2" id="PANT2">
    <option></option>
    <option>28</option>
    <option>29</option>
    <option>30</option>
    <option>31</option>
    <option>32</option>
    <option>33</option>
    <option>34</option>
    <option>35</option>
    <option>36</option>
    <option>37</option>
    <option>38</option>
    <option>39</option>
    <option>40</option>
    <option>41</option>
    <option>42</option>
    <option>43</option>
    <option>44</option>
    <option>45</option>
    <option>46</option>
    <option>47</option>
    <option>48</option>
  </select>
  <br />

  <br>
  QTY
  <select name="QTY4" id="QTY4">
    <option></option>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
  </select>
  <br />
  <br>
  SAFETY SHOES
  <select name="SAFETYSHOES" id="SAFETYSHOES">
    <option></option>
    <option>5</option>
    <option>6</option>
    <option>7</option>
    <option>8</option>
    <option>9</option>
    <option>10</option>
    <option>11</option>
    <option>12</option>
  </select>
  <br />
  <br>
  QTY
  <select name="QTY5" id="QTY5">
    <option></option>
    <option>1</option>
  </select>
  <br />
  <br>
  JACKET
  <select name="JACKET" id="JACKET">
    <option></option>
    <option>S</option>
    <option>M</option>
    <option>L</option>
    <option>XL</option>
  </select>
  <br />
  <br>
  QTY
  <select name="QTY6" id="QTY6">
    <option></option>
    <option>1</option>
  </select>
  <br />
  <br>
  SAFETY VEST 
  <select name="SAFETYVEST" id="SAFETYVEST">
    <option></option>
    <option>1</option>
  </select>
  <br />
  <br>
  POUCH 
  <select name="POUCH" id="POUCH">
    <option></option>
    <option>1</option>
  </select>
  <br />
  <br>
  LANYARD 
  <select name="LANYARD" id="LANYARD">
    <option></option>
    <option>1</option>
  </select>
  <br />
  <br>
  REASONS/REMARKS
  <br >
  <textarea name="RR" id="RR" cols="40" rows="8" placeholder="Fill this if you are exchanging kit"></textarea>

</form>
<input type="button" id="b1" onClick="insert_value()" value="Insert"></input>
```

Answer (score 3):

I have changed input type button to submit and it should be inside the form element. This is the updated code.

```
<form>
    NAME
    <input type="text" name="NAME" id="NAME" required/> <br />
    <br>
    EMAIL
    <input type="email" name="EMAIL" id="EMAIL"> <br />
    <br>
    DEPARTMENT
    <select name="DEPARTMENT" id="DEPARTMENT">
        <option>HR</option>
        <option>DMS</option>
        <option>RIM</option>
    </select><br />
    <br>
    PURPOSE
    <select name="PURPOSE" id="PURPOSE">
        <option>NEW KIT</option>
        <option>EXCHANGE KIT</option>
    </select><br/>
    <br>
    SHIRT 1
    <select name="SHIRT1" id="SHIRT1">
    <option></option>
        <option>XS</option>
        <option>S</option>
        <option>M</option>
        <option>L</option>
        <option>XL</option>
        <option>2XL</option>
        <option>3XL</option>
        <option>4XL</option>
        <option>5XL</option>
        <option>6XL</option>
        <option>7XL</option>
    </select><br />
    <br>
    QTY
    <SELECT name="QTY1" id="QTY1">
    <option></option>
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
    </SELECT> <br />
    <br>
    PANT 1
    <select name="PANT1" id="PANT1">
        <option></option>
        <option>24</option>
        <option>25</option>
        <option>26</option>
        <option>27</option>
        <option>28</option>
        <option>29</option>
        <option>30</option>
        <option>31</option>
        <option>32</option>
        <option>33</option>
        <option>34</option>
        <option>35</option>
        <option>36</option>
        <option>37</option>
        <option>38</option>
        <option>39</option>
        <option>40</option>
        <option>41</option>
        <option>42</option>
        <option>43</option>
        <option>44</option>
        <option>45</option>
        <option>46</option>
        <option>47</option>
        <option>48</option>
    </select><br />
    <br>
    QTY
    <select name="QTY2" id="QTY2">
        <option></option>
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
    </select> <br />
    <br>
    SHIRT 2
    <select name="SHIRT2" id="SHIRT2">
        <option></option>
        <option>XS</option>
        <option>S</option>
        <option>M</option>
        <option>L</option>
        <option>XL</option>
        <option>2XL</option>
        <option>3XL</option>
        <option>4XL</option>
        <option>5XL</option>
    </select> <br />
    <br>
    QTY
    <SELECT name="QTY3" id="QTY3">
        <option></option>
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
    </SELECT>
    <br />
    <br>
    PANT 2
    <select name="PANT2" id="PANT2">
        <option></option>
        <option>28</option>
        <option>29</option>
        <option>30</option>
        <option>31</option>
        <option>32</option>
        <option>33</option>
        <option>34</option>
        <option>35</option>
        <option>36</option>
        <option>37</option>
        <option>38</option>
        <option>39</option>
        <option>40</option>
        <option>41</option>
        <option>42</option>
        <option>43</option>
        <option>44</option>
        <option>45</option>
        <option>46</option>
        <option>47</option>
        <option>48</option>
    </select>
    <br />

    <br>
    QTY
    <select name="QTY4" id="QTY4">
        <option></option>
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
    </select>
    <br />
    <br>
    SAFETY SHOES
    <select name="SAFETYSHOES" id="SAFETYSHOES">
        <option></option>
        <option>5</option>
        <option>6</option>
        <option>7</option>
        <option>8</option>
        <option>9</option>
        <option>10</option>
        <option>11</option>
        <option>12</option>
    </select>
    <br />
    <br>
    QTY
    <select name="QTY5" id="QTY5">
        <option></option>
        <option>1</option>
    </select>
    <br />
    <br>
    JACKET
    <select name="JACKET" id="JACKET">
        <option></option>
        <option>S</option>
        <option>M</option>
        <option>L</option>
        <option>XL</option>
    </select>
    <br />
    <br>
    QTY
    <select name="QTY6" id="QTY6">
        <option></option>
        <option>1</option>
    </select>
    <br />
    <br>
    SAFETY VEST 
    <select name="SAFETYVEST" id="SAFETYVEST">
        <option></option>
        <option>1</option>
    </select>
    <br />
    <br>
    POUCH 
    <select name="POUCH" id="POUCH">
        <option></option>
        <option>1</option>
    </select>
    <br />
    <br>
    LANYARD 
    <select name="LANYARD" id="LANYARD">
        <option></option>
        <option>1</option>
    </select>
    <br />
    <br>
    REASONS/REMARKS
    <br >
    <textarea name="RR" id="RR" cols="40" rows="8" placeholder="Fill this if you are exchanging kit"></textarea>
  <input type="submit" id="b1" onClick="insert_value()" value="Insert"></input>
</form>
```

To enable quantity on select change, These are the changes I have made in 1 of your select box, you can replicate the same for others

```
<select name="SHIRT1" id="SHIRT1" onchange="enableQuantity(this.value, 'QTY1')">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="XS">XS</option>
        <option value="S">S</option>
        <option value="M">M</option>
    </select><br />
    <br>
    QTY
    <SELECT name="QTY1" id="QTY1" disabled>
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
    </SELECT>
```

and javascript

```
function enableQuantity(selectValue, qtyEle) {
  document.getElementById(qtyEle).disabled = selectValue ? false : true;
}
```

Hope this works

Comment: Hi, it did not work even if the input type button inside the form element.